# How to tokenize text if the model was trained with X using texts_to_matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tokenize

I'm new to TensorFlow, I was wondering how to tokenize a string to predict if the X_train, X_test was tokenized with texts_to_matrix. The model is used for classification, to distinguish different categories from news (business, politics, sports, ...).

```py
tokenize = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=1000, char_level=False)
tokenize.fit_on_texts(X_train_1)
X_train = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(X_train_1)
X_test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(X_test_1)

model.fit ...

test_text = 'Im super insecure AND unsure of everything'
test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(test_text)
print(test.shape) # should be (1000,)
(43, 1000)
test_pred = model.predict(np.array([test]))

text_labels[np.argmax(test_pred)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-51b109f3505f> in <module>()
----> 1 text_labels[np.argmax(test_pred)]

IndexError: index 78 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!